# Error running Maven

Tags: maven

I am trying to build a maven (latest version 3.1.1) project and for some reason when I run any maven command, such as maven clean, or maven compile, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.reset()V from class org.slf4j.MavenSlf4jFriend
at org.slf4j.MavenSlf4jFriend.reset(MavenSlf4jFriend.java:33)
at org.apache.maven.cli.logging.impl.Slf4jSimpleConfiguration.activate(Slf4jSimpleConfiguration.java:60)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.logging(MavenCli.java:348)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:205)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: Recently had the same trouble, with Eclipse though. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: which version of slf4j-api you are using?

Comment: That error is indicative of having multiple slf4j libs with different versions on the classpath. Try picking newer versions in your maven project.

Comment: @Reddy I haven't installed it. I just installed maven and when I type in mvn in terminal, this error appears.

Comment: @Alex, It's not about installing. It's about your project dependencies. Plain maven will not have code related to com.intelliJ.rt.*******

Comment: @Reddy here is the same error from terminal https://ghostbin.com/paste/uz37x

Comment: @Reddy Its defiantly not a project dependencies issue. When I go to Terminal, I see https://ghostbin.com/paste/9fj3m

Comment: @Alex sorry for my misunderstanding. Did you try with Maven 3.0.5 or Maven 2? If no problems, with them, may be a bug in latest release

Comment: @David, for you. It's not issue. It's normal. You didn't mention any params to maven. try "mvn archetype:generate" or "mvn -version"

Comment: @Reddy Its not a bug. It could be something locally on his machine though. I have version 3.1.1 and I have no issues. No clue, very weird I think.

Comment: @Reddy I know its not a issue. I was just trying to help Alex by showing him what it supposed to look like.

Comment: @Alex, seems like an issue with Maven. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201311.mbox/%3C529A3D2B.8050709@austin.rr.com%3E

this is much more similar to you and it happened with 3.1.1

Comment: @Alex, btw which JDK you are using? OpenJDK or Oracle JDK? or some other

Comment: @Reddy I switched to 3.0.5 from 3.1.1 and the error is gone. Not sure as to why. Thanks though

Comment: Problem can be caused by a difference between the Maven used in the PATH and the one referenced in your M2_HOME environment variable. It often happens that you do change the M2_HOME to use another Maven version, but still using the "old" mvn executable, which can lead to such issues, as the bootstrap classloader is taken from the mvn executable.

Comment: I have had same problem, I started using Maven 2 instead of Maven 3 and the problem was solved. This issue happens with Maven 3.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with Maven on OS X 10.9 installed using Brew. It turns out Maven brought its own libs including `slf4j` into `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.2/libexec/lib`. However I already had another version of `slf4j` in my classpath in `/Library/Java/Extensions`

Solution: remove slf4j from the OS X default classpath so that Maven can use its version without conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Change the Java JDK version and reinstall the maven. It worked for me. Even I faced the same error but could not found working solution. I have changed my JDK version 1.8 to JDK 9.0.1 and reinstalled Maven and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove slf4j libraries from `java/path/jre/lib/ext/`

Then it will work